# Separate one-off code paths

Tags: c++11

I'm implementing an application with different code paths that shall be chosen once at startup and then fixed forevermore for that execution- for example, choosing D3D11 or D3D9 rendering path.

Obviously I don't want to duplicate all my other code.

Is run-time inheritance (no virtual inheritance) a fair solution? I don't want to waste a bunch of performance making virtual lookups when the type was fixed long ago. Not just that, but it makes me nervous that the functions can't be inlined and whether or not it affects RVO and NRVO and such. Am I just being over-concerned about this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern ?

Comment: How is that not run-time inheritance?

Comment: You can do the Strategy pattern with Templates, http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/strategy.html

Comment: @oluies: So you want me to template my *entire* program? The amount of cocking around this would entail is unbelievable- trust me, I already tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided that since the number of paths is minimal that I would compile them as a DLL and load e.g. D3D9Main(), which would be compliled using the preprocessor to choose the types at compile-time. Much easier than using templates and much faster/easier than using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use generic components described in ["Modern C++ Design"](http://erdani.com/book/main.html), but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.